# Does Simple Injector have a way to Register with an instance factory in combination with a TypeFactoryContext?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, log4net, simple-injector

I'm working on a legacy code base that seriously needs refactoring towards SOLID principles. We are adding the Simple Injector dependency injection container to the mix as a first step.

For one of the registrations I need something very much like the RegisterConditional example for Log4Net, i.e:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(ILogger),
    c => typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);
```

Difference is that I want to inject an instance returned by a factory method that takes the c.Consumer.ImplementationType as input:

```
container.Register???(
    typeof(ILogger),
    c => LoggerProvider.GetLogger(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Transient);
```

Can this be accomplished in Simple Injector?

I have read the answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087864/does-simple-injector-have-a-way-to-registerconditional-with-object-factory), but that does not suffice. The ImplementationType needs to be handed to the instance factory.

For the time being, I will implement a **Logger<TParent>** and use that in the RegisterConditional call:

```
public class Logger<TParent> : ILogger
{
    private readonly ILogger _decoratedLogger;

    public Logger()
    {
        _decoratedLogger = Logger.GetLogger(typeof(TParent));
    }
}
```

Comment: "We are adding the Simple Injector dependency injection container to the mix as a first step." You might want to start using a DI Container later on. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32033648/264697

Comment: Good point. We did consider going for Pure DI for a brief moment. However, the code base is used for multiple applications. Each requiring a composition root that would quickly impair maintainability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this be accomplished in Simple Injector?

Yes and no.

- **No**, this isn't supported using the `RegisterConditional` and that's because Simple Injector tries to push you towards registering types, so it can verify and diagnose your object graph as much as possible. Preferred way is to create a proxy class much as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25113659/264697). It basically explains your current solution, but has a `Logger<T>` that inherits from `LogImp` instead, since that leads to a simpler solution.
- **Yes**, this is possible, but you'll have to revert to using a custom `IDependencyInjectionBehavior` as explained [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/295#issuecomment-318740952) (the example is for Serilog, but can be easily rewritten to log4net). The first method however is preferred if possible.

Comment: "but has a Logger<T> that inherits from LogImp instead".
Ended up doing exactly that ;-)